# Count different values of 0 from a MySQL query

Tags: sql, count

I'm trying to make this query:

```
SELECT    monthPosted,
          sector,
          COUNT(sumaAbas) as abasNum,
          SUM(sumaAbas) as abas,
          COUNT(usdAmount) AS totalNum,
          SUM(usdAmount) AS total
FROM      DatosSpend
WHERE     negotiableProcGl='Y'
GROUP BY  sector
```

The problem I'm getting here is that the `COUNT(usdAmount)` is counting all values also having a 0 in it.

How can I ignore the count of values=0?

Comment: `WHERE value != 0`??

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think it's not worth it as an answer, it's too short xD

Comment: Short is good @Mehdi if it solves the problem.

Comment: @JayBlanchard fair enough I added it. OP can you tell me what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to add `monthPosted` to Group By?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate functions ignore `null`s. You could use a `case` expression to convert `0`s to `null`s and thus skip them. E.g.:

```
SELECT   monthPosted,
         sector, 
         COUNT(sumaAbas) as abasNum, 
         SUM(sumaAbas) as abas, 
         COUNT(CASE usdAmount WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS totalNum, 
         SUM(usdAmount) AS total 
FROM     DatosSpend 
WHERE    negotiableProcGl = 'Y' 
GROUP BY sector
```

Comment: When there's a CASE there's always NULLIF, too: `COUNT(NULLIF(usdAmount, 0))

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply exclude the 0 values in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE negotiableProcGl='Y' AND value != 0
```

Where value is your column name